# How to call action method by clicking on row inside foreach?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I use mvc5 project and I use bootstrap 3.

I have this partial page:

```
        @model IEnumerable<GeomindEnterprise.Models.ApplicationGroup>
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <div class="row margin-bottom-8">
                    <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-3">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</div>
                    <div class="col-sm-7">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LayoutID)</div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
    </div>
```

whenever I click generated row above I need to call this action method:

```
    public ActionResult GetLayers(ApplicationGroup model)
    {
       //some logic
    }
```

I tried this way:

```
           @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
        Html.ActionLink(<div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row margin-bottom-8">
                            <div class="col-sm-2">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-7">@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.LayoutID)</div>
                        </div>
                        </div>,
                        new { controller = "Articles", action = "Details",model = item })}
                    </div>
```

But the attitude above didnt work.

How do I implement it?

Comment: It would need to be `new { controller = "Articles", action = "Details", item }` but you should not be passing the whole model to the GET method - just its ID (and get it again in the controller. And you should just handle this with javascript rather (not attempting to put the whole html inside the `<a>` element which will not work

Comment: `public ActionResult GetLayers(int? id, ApplicationGroup model)` => better than passing entire `ApplicationGroup` with anchor link. And why using multiple `DisplayFor` helpers inside `ActionLink` (just put a column which contains view detail link with proper ID)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `@Html.ActionLink()` to generate you `<a>` element because the first parameter is a `string` and it will be encoded (your html will not be rendered as html). In addition, its generally not advisable to send the whole model in a query string. Apart from the ugly query string it creates, you risk exceeding the query string limit and throwing an exception. Instead pass just the ID of the record and get it again in the GET method

If you want to handle clicking the `<div>` rather than adding an additional column for a 'Details' link, then add a class name and a `data-` attribute for the url to your `<div>` and use javascript/jquery to handle the `.click()` event, for example

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container-fluid details" data-id="@item.yourIdProperty">
        ....
    </div>
}
```

and the jQuery script would be

```
var baseUrl = '@Url.Action("Details", "Articles")
$('.details').click(function() {
    var id = $(this).data('id');
    location.href = baseUrl + '/' + id;
});
```

Which would post back to (assuming your using the default route)

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) // not GetLayers as per your question
```

If you really do want to post back the whole model, then

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="container-fluid details" data-url="@Url.Action"Details", "Articles", item)">
        ....
    </div>
}

$('.details').click(function() {
    location.href = $(this).data('url');
});
```

Note that the 3rd parameter of `Url.Action()` is your model, not an anonymous object containing your model. The method serializes each property of your model to a query string value.